# javascript not loading on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a very simple page at this point and am adding a menu that using javascript to display a submenu.  I can't get the javascript to load and I am not getting any errors using Firebug. I have stripped my page down to pretty much bare content except for the javascript, but it still won't load.  The CSS associated with the menu does load. I didn't write the javascript, but have a basic concept of how it works.

Here is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Journal</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link href="http://celt.miamioh.edu/ject/images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">

    <script src="http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/menuscript.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menustyle.css" media="screen, print" />
</head>
<body>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
<a href="Link 1" onmouseover="setOverImg('1','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu1','button1');" onmouseout="setOutImg('1','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu1\')',delay);" target="http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/about.php"><img src="buttons/button1up.png" border="0" id="button1" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><a href="Link 2" onmouseover="setOverImg('2','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu2','button2');" onmouseout="setOutImg('2','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu2\')',delay);" target="http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/archive.php"><img src="buttons/button2up.png" border="0" id="button2" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><a href="Link 3" onmouseover="setOverImg('3','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu3','button3');" onmouseout="setOutImg('3','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu3\')',delay);" target="http://celt.miamioh.edu/journals/subscription/subscriptionpage.php"><img src="buttons/button3up.png" border="0" id="button3" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
</td></tr></table>

<p>Test page for javascript functionality.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is he js:

```
subInfo[2] = new Array();
subInfo[3] = new Array();


//*** SET SUB MENUS TEXT LINKS AND TARGETS HERE ***//
subInfo[1][1] = new Array("Overview","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/about.php","");
subInfo[1][2] = new Array("Free Sample Issue","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/issue.php?v=19&n=1","");
subInfo[1][3] = new Array("Editorial Board/Staff","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/staff.php","");
subInfo[1][4] = new Array("Manuscript Submission","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/submission.php","");

subInfo[2][1] = new Array("Current Issue","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/issue.php?v=25&n=2","");
subInfo[2][2] = new Array("Issue Archive","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/archive.php","");
subInfo[2][3] = new Array("Special Issue Archive","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/special.php","");
subInfo[2][4] = new Array("Search Archive","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/search.php","");

subInfo[3][1] = new Array("Journal Subscription","http://celt.miamioh.edu/journals/subscription/subscriptionpage.php","");
subInfo[3][2] = new Array("Order Back Issue","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/order_backissues.php","");
subInfo[3][3] = new Array("Order Individual Articles","http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/order_articles.php","");


//*** SET SUB MENU POSITION ( RELATIVE TO BUTTON ) ***//
var xSubOffset = 9;
var ySubOffset = 34;



//*** NO MORE SETTINGS BEYOND THIS POINT ***//
var overSub = false;
var delay = 1000;
totalButtons = upSources.length;

// GENERATE SUB MENUS
for ( x=0; x<totalButtons; x++) {
    // SET EMPTY DIV FOR BUTTONS WITHOUT SUBMENU
    if ( subInfo[x+1].length < 1 ) { 
        document.write('<div id="submenu' + (x+1) + '">');
    // SET DIV FOR BUTTONS WITH SUBMENU
    } else {
        document.write('<div id="submenu' + (x+1) + '" class="dropmenu" ');
        document.write('onMouseOver="overSub=true;');
        document.write('setOverImg(\'' + (x+1) + '\',\'\');"');
        document.write('onMouseOut="overSub=false;');
        document.write('setTimeout(\'hideSubMenu(\\\'submenu' + (x+1) + '\\\')\',delay);');
        document.write('setOutImg(\'' + (x+1) + '\',\'\');">');


        document.write('<ul>');
        for ( k=0; k<subInfo[x+1].length-1; k++ ) {
            document.write('<li>');
            document.write('<a href="' + subInfo[x+1][k+1][1] + '" ');
            document.write('target="' + subInfo[x+1][k+1][2] + '">');
            document.write( subInfo[x+1][k+1][0] + '</a>');
            document.write('</li>');
        }
        document.write('</ul>');
    }
    document.write('</div>');
}





//*** MAIN BUTTONS FUNCTIONS ***//
// PRELOAD MAIN MENU BUTTON IMAGES
function preload() {
    for ( x=0; x<totalButtons; x++ ) {
        buttonUp = new Image();
        buttonUp.src = buttonFolder + upSources[x];
        buttonOver = new Image();
        buttonOver.src = buttonFolder + overSources[x];
    }
}

// SET MOUSEOVER BUTTON
function setOverImg(But, ID) {
    document.getElementById('button' + But + ID).src = buttonFolder + overSources[But-1];
}

// SET MOUSEOUT BUTTON
function setOutImg(But, ID) {
    document.getElementById('button' + But + ID).src = buttonFolder + upSources[But-1];
}



//*** SUB MENU FUNCTIONS ***//
// GET ELEMENT ID MULTI BROWSER
function getElement(id) {
    return document.getElementById ? document.getElementById(id) : document.all ? document.all(id) : null; 
}

// GET X COORDINATE
function getRealLeft(id) { 
    var el = getElement(id);
    if (el) { 
        xPos = el.offsetLeft;
        tempEl = el.offsetParent;
        while (tempEl != null) {
            xPos += tempEl.offsetLeft;
            tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
        } 
        return xPos;
    } 
} 

// GET Y COORDINATE
function getRealTop(id) {
    var el = getElement(id);
    if (el) { 
        yPos = el.offsetTop;
        tempEl = el.offsetParent;
        while (tempEl != null) {
            yPos += tempEl.offsetTop;
            tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
        }
        return yPos;
    }
}

// MOVE OBJECT TO COORDINATE
function moveObjectTo(objectID,x,y) {
    var el = getElement(objectID);
    el.style.left = x;
    el.style.top = y;
}

// MOVE SUBMENU TO CORRESPONDING BUTTON
function showSubMenu(subID, buttonID) {
    hideAllSubMenus();
    butX = getRealLeft(buttonID);
    butY = getRealTop(buttonID);
    moveObjectTo(subID,butX+xSubOffset, butY+ySubOffset);
}

// HIDE ALL SUB MENUS
function hideAllSubMenus() {
    for ( x=0; x<totalButtons; x++) {
        moveObjectTo("submenu" + (x+1) + "",-500, -500 );
    }
}

// HIDE ONE SUB MENU
function hideSubMenu(subID) {
    if ( overSub == false ) {
        moveObjectTo(subID,-500, -500);
    }
}



//preload();
```

Any help on what is wrong or even how I can further troubleshoot it myself to find out what is wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: You have errors in your javascript.

Comment: Well, if you input "http://celt.edu/newject/menuscript.js" into a browser, you'll see that it's not loading, so...

Comment: On top of that, if you're overhauling, you should really consider bringing this up to date with modern event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a copy of your file [at JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/mogopitasosa/1/edit?html,js,output) and can verify that the javascript does indeed run.

I also noticed you have code commented out at the bottom `//preload();` and perhaps this is what you are expecting to execute?

If you still are not getting the expected results try adding a `debugger;` statement and running in Firebug and the code should break on the line you added that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your src link is incorrect, to match the URLs in the js file it should be

```
http://celt.miamioh.edu/newject/menuscript.js
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not it.  I was editing the URLs for another reason.  In my source files they all match.  Still no joy.

Comment: when I tried your code the js is missing references for buttonFolder, upSources, and overSources.  Are you defining these somewhere?  Otherwise, it does load and try to execute but gets hungup on the main button functions since it doesn't know what those variables are.